# Lightning Component Get AccountId js error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying get accountId with lightning component. I developed custom controller,controller.js and component. Everything looks true but I have error and it doesnt work.
Error is:

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.
>   Action failed: forceChatter:lightningComponent$controller$doInit [Error while creating content for lightning component quick action]
>   quickActionHandlerHelper.js failed to create component - forceChatter:lightningComponent

This is my component

```
<aura:component controller="GetAccountController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" access="global" />
</aura:component>
```

This is my custom contorller

```
global with sharing class GetAccountController {

    @AuraEnabled
    global static void setAccountId(Id actId) {
        try{

          Account ac = new Account(ID=actId,Site=actID);
          update ac;  
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }               
    }
}
```

This is my controller.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    var artId = component.get("v.actId");

    console.log(artId);

    action.setParams({
        "artId":artId
    });
    // Queue this action to send to the server
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

and this is my helper.js

```
({
helperMethod : function() {

}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`force:hasRecordId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation) (thanks to sfdcfox for the link and correction) interface you're declaring provides a `recordId` attribute that you should use to access the record Id, via `component.get("v.recordId");` You do not have an attribute `actId`, which you try to access. Presumably your error is happening somewhere within the `init` handler for that reason, which then results in the inscrutable error message you're receiving.

You also never declare `action` in your init method, so you'll get an error there too. You need to get controller actions with `component.get("c.myActionName");`

Comment: You do not declare `recordId`; the interface does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was looking at apparently [out of date documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html). (I can't find the current doc - they seem to have 404ed the link).

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation